# How do I make my web browser app show up in "Open with..." when clicking a link?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

When I click a link in something like Gmail, how can I have my web browser show up as an option to open said link? And what code would I implement to go about it? Even just a link to the correct documentation would be incredibly helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Read up about intent filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing to declare this `<intent-filter>` in your Manifest

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:scheme="http"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thanks for being more specific with this, that worked perfectly! I then was able to take the Intent and make a URI that would load into my WebView, and I'm thrilled. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

For your app to be on the list of apps, you need an `<intent-filter>` that support web browsing. You can look at this link as a [reference](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Browser.git/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml) and determine what you need to add.

Comment: I get that that calls for the browsers to be pulled up as a list, but how do I get MY browser in said list is what I mean? It has a working WebView and everything. Thanks!

Comment: I know what you are talking about you need to deal with this in your Android Manifest

Comment: You just answered the *opposite* of what the OP wants.

Comment: I didn't just answer, I answered 16 hours ago and I'm trying to help out.

Comment: I figured it out via your references after some research, thanks Phillip.